# Empty page while running servlet XQuery in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, xquery

I have deployed a servlet which contain Xquery code, but when i run it in localhost tomcat it makes me an empty page.
here is my servlet:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.xml.xquery.*; 
import com.saxonica.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource;  

public class XQueryTester extends HttpServlet {  

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try { 
    //InputStream xqy = new FileInputStream(new File("courses.xqy"));  

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();  
        XQConnection conn = ds.getConnection();  
        XQPreparedExpression exp = conn.prepareExpression("for $x in doc('/WEB-INF/courses.xml')/courses/course return $x/title");  
        XQResultSequence result = exp.executeQuery();  
        while (result.next()) {  
        //out.println("---------------------------");
            out.println(result.getItemAsString(null));  
        }   

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    catch (XQException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    }
   }
```

So can you please help me to solve my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Either `result.next()` is always false, or there possibly is an error printed to server console you did not provide the stacktrace from.

Comment: I am not familiar with Tomcat or servlets, as for XQuery, to check where the query might fail, what does `doc-available('/WEB-INF/courses.xml')` return, if that returns true, how does the input document look?

Comment: it's an xml document which must return the title of the books that i h've metionned , before it works normally but now maybe when i've add the .jar for exist-db maybe it's didn't work :/

Comment: Do you expect Saxon to get the data from an eXist data base?

Comment: and here are the .jar that i've use them

    saxon9he.jar
    saxon9-xqj.jar
    saxon9-test.jar
    saxon9-unpack.jar
    antlr-2.7.7.jar
    bcprov-jdk-15on-1.60.jar
    caffeine-2.6.2.jar
    cglib-nodep-3.2.6.jar
    clj-ds-0.0.4.jar

Comment: commons-codec-1.11.jar
    commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
    commons-configuration2-2.2.jar
    commons-io-2.6.jar
    commons-logging-1.2.jar
    commons-pool-1.6.jar
    exist.jar

Comment: icu4j-59_1.jar
    icu4j-localespi-59_1.jar
    j8fu-1.21.jar
    jackson-core-2.9.5.jar
    jargo-0.4.14.jar
    jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
    jctools-core-2.1.2.jar
    hline-0.9.94.jar
    jsr305-3.0.2.jar

Comment: jta-1.1.jar
    log4j-1.2-api-2.11.0.jar
    log4j-api-2.11.0.jar
    log4j-core-2.11.0.jar

Comment: log4j-jul-2.11.0.jar
    log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.0.jar
    lz4-java-1.5.0.jar
    pkg-java-1.1.jar
    quartz-2.3.0.jar
    rsyntaxtextarea-2.6.1.jar
    slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
    ws-commons-util-1.0.2.jar
    xmldb-api-1.1-patched.jar
    xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar
    xmlrpc-common-3.1.3.jar
    xmlrpc-server-3.1.3.jar

Comment: yes i expect saxon to get the data from exist-db

Comment: I don't think you need Saxon to run XQuery with eXist, it has its own XQuery implementation and its own programming API. http://xqj.net/exist/ seems to be one way to use the XQJ API with eXist.